# What's this roleplaying game that came with a video and a box?

Tags: product-identification

I've got a player for a one-off that I'm running at the weekend who says that he's roleplayed before, but can't remember what it was. All he can remember is that it came with a video and "had a box". I vaguely remember having heard of some old game that involved a video, but the prevalance of role playing video games makes it basically impossible to find through search engines.

It's not really important, but I was interested and figured someone on here was bound to have heard of such a thing if it exists. Anyone have any ideas what it might have been?

Comment: There was a TSR game called DragonStrike that came with a VHS tutorial. There were also "interactive" VHS games, but most would be classed as board games. You might have better luck asking at the board games SE.

Comment: I played DragonStrike last week and can confirm it came with a VHS tape about the game. It sure wasn't a tutorial though... more like a tv show inspired by the game. A terrible, terrible tv show. But hilarious now!

Comment: @cr0m - It was hilarious at release time too. I loved that thing as a kid, because it was crazy over the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to recall an introductory D&D box from the mid 1990's that had a video.

There were several D&D boxes with audio CD's; One was a starter set, called "[First Quest](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/56515/first-quest)" (The others were supplements.)

The [Dragon Strike](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1149/dragon-strike) game was released by TSR, has a hybrid play mode (That is, it's a board game but uses a GM, and can be used as an RPG; to the non-RPGer, it can be easily mistaken for an RPG. THis is the most likely one to be so confused. It has a "Learn to Play" VHS cassette.

The [DragonRaid RPG](http://www.dragonraid.net/) also has an audio CD to assist new players. There was, at one point, discussion of a VHS cassette showing as well as telling, but I don't know if it got off the ground. (And while not a bad game, it's definitely very focused on a Christian allegory mode similar to Narnia, but more obvious about it. (My copy predated the CD version, and had audio cassette.)

[Il gioco di ruolo di Ken il Guerriero](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/1817/il-gioco-di-ruolo-di-ken-il-guerriero) was sold bundled with the VHS of Fist of the Northstar in Italy; the Game doesn't use the video, but is based upon the video.

Answer (score 4):

[Demon Hunters](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/45922/demon-hunters-role-playing-game) (a cortex game) includes a dvd that has a Hunter training video. It is hilarious and sets the stage for the setting very well.